# Expected process to exit with [0], but received ''

Tags: shell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a `chef` `execute` `resource` in my `recipe`. When my `chef-client` runs this resource I get the error :

```
 Expected process to exit with [0], but received ''
```

The resource :

```
  execute "startHAPROXY" do
    command "cd /home/#{node["haproxyUser"]}/haproxy && ./start.sh"
    action :nothing
  end
```

start.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep haproxy | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
cd /home/lb/haproxy
/home/lb/haproxy/haproxy -f /home/lb/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
exit $?
```

when I run it manually (`./start.sh; echo $?`) it echos `0` but still when `chef-client` runs it, it fails.

Comment: Have you tried adding `set -e`?

Comment: In `start.sh` or in the run command? I don't know what `set -e` does/is...

Comment: Yea. It tells the script to exit early on failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

the recipe:

```
execute "startHAPROXY" do
  command "./start.sh"
  cwd "/home/#{node["haproxyUser"]}/haproxy"
  action :nothing
end
```

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep haproxy | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
cd /home/lb/haproxy
/home/lb/haproxy/haproxy -f /home/lb/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

1. You should better use `cwd` attribute of `execute` resource to change working directory.
2. Changed script to "bash" and added "-e" for it to fail on the first error it encounters.
3. You don't need `exit $?` at the end as exit status of the script will automatically be the exit status of last command in it.

Comment: Ok, understood, but WHY?